# Fastest way to check if element is in both vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

So, think that we have two vectors, vec1 and vec2. What would be the fastest way to only perform some operation to elements, which are in both vectors. 
This far, I have made this. Simply, how can we achieve this faster, or is there any way:

```
vector<Test*> vec1;
vector<Test*> vec2;

//Fill both of the vectors, with vec1 containing all existing 
//objects of Test, and vec2 containing some of them.


for (Test* test : vec1){

    //Check if test is in vec2
    if (std::find(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), test) != vec2.end){

        //Do some stuff

    }

}
```

Comment: Are the vectors sorted? Can you use another data structure?

Comment: @Borgleader even if they are not, you could stable sort them in O(nlogn+mlogm) time, which sure beats the pants off of O(n*m)

Comment: If these are sorted, `std::upper_bound` would be pretty helpful. If not, there are a number of ways to do this, with a `std::unordered_set<Test*>` being one way worth considering.

Comment: @WhozCraig if they are sorted you can use `std::set_union`

Comment: @IdeaHat yeah, the set-ops in `<algorithms>` continue to elude me as I rarely have use for them. An excellent point. Btw, did you mean  [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)?

Comment: @WhozCraig haha yeah obviosly I don't use them often either, but they are handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to `std::unordered_set`

```
vector<Test*> vec1;
vector<Test*> vec2;

//Fill both of the vectors, with vec1 containing all existing 
//objects of Test, and vec2 containing some of them.
std::unordered_set<Test*> set2(vec2.begin(),vec2.end());

for (Test* t : vec1) {
   //O(1) lookup in hash set
   if (set2.find(t)!=set2.end()) {
     //stuff
    }
 }
```

O(n+m), where n is the number of elements in vec1, m is the number of elements in vec2
    }

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is O(M*N) because it calls `std::find` linear in the number of elements of `vec2` for each element of `vec1`. You can improve upon it in several ways:

- **Sorting `vec2` would let you reduce the time to O((N+M)*Log M)** - i.e. you can use binary search on the range `vec2.begin(), vec2.end()`
- **Sorting both vectors would let you search in O(N*Log N + M*Log M)** - you could use an algorithm similar to merging sorted ranges to find matching pairs in linear time
- **Using a hash set for `vec2` element would let you reduce the time to O(N+M)** - now both the construction time of the set and the search in it are linear.

Comment: Silly thought...if N<<M, then with the sorting you can sort just the smaller and then do binary search over it, O(N Log N + M log N). Not pretty, and still not as good as hash set.

Comment: @IdeaHat Generally speaking, it's best to check the relative sizes of the two vectors, and sort/hash/etc. the smaller of the two.